# Empty List not updating in a while loop

Tags: java, list

I'm trying to make something that gives us the multiplicative root and the multiplicative persistence of a number.
So I made a method that gives us a list with 2 elements- the root and the persistence. So I made an empty list named answers and then added the elements in an if and while loop.
But when I then tried to print the List it gives an error.
Here's the code I made:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long number = 123456789;
        String dupeNumber=String.valueOf(number);
        List<Long> answers;
        if (dupeNumber.length() > 1) {
            while (dupeNumber.length() > 1) {
                long intNumber = Integer.parseInt(dupeNumber);
                List<Long> digits = separated(intNumber);
                answers = prodDigits(digits);
                dupeNumber=String.valueOf(answers);
                System.out.println(dupeNumber);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(answers);
    }
    static List<Long> separated(long number) {
        List<Long> digits = new ArrayList<>();
        while (number > 0) {
            digits.add((number % 10));
            number -= (number % 10);
            number /= 10;
        }
        return digits;
    }
    static List<Long> prodDigits(List<Long> digits) {
        List<Long> answers = new ArrayList<>();
        long product = 1;
        long persistence = 0;
        for (long i : digits) {
            product *= i;
            persistence += 1;
        }
        answers.add(product);
        answers.add(persistence);
        return answers;
    }
}
```

The error and the error line is

```
- 18:28 java: variable answers might not have been initialized
```

I want the output to be like this:
If the number given is 123456789: [0, 2] as 1*2*3*4*5*6*7*8*9=362800 and 3*6*2*8*0*0=0 and multiplication happened 2 times.

Comment: The compiler doesn't evaluate far enough to see that `dupeNumber` is never empty to start. (Note that your `if` is pointless anyway, since you're immediately checking again in `while`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you don't necessarily initialize the `answers` variable (from the compiler's point of view) and try to access it. Add a start value to it:

```
List<Long> answers = null; // or some default value, like new ArrayList<>()
```

[How to fix "variable might not have been initialized" error in Java?](https://www.java67.com/2016/07/how-to-fix-variable-might-not-have-been-initialized-error-in-java.html#ixzz72jD24rOZ)

Update:

Instead of counting `multiplicative persistence` you count number of digits in number:

```
for (long i : digits) {
    product *= i;
    persistence += 1;
}
```

Insted you need to count number of calls of `prodDigits()` before number will stop changing.

[Multiplicative Persistence](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MultiplicativePersistence.html)

Final code may look like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long number = 123456789;

    int persistence = 0;

    while(number > 9) {
        number = prodDigits(separated(number));
        persistence++;
    }

    System.out.println(number + " " + persistence);
}

static List<Long> separated(long number) {
    List<Long> digits = new ArrayList<>();
    while(number > 0) {
        digits.add((number % 10));
        number -= (number % 10);
        number /= 10;
    }
    return digits;
}

static long prodDigits(List<Long> digits) {
    long product = 1;

    for(long i : digits) {
        product *= i;
    }

    return product;
}
```

We call `prodDigits()` until number consists of at least two digits. Also we count number of calls of `prodDigits` to find `multiplicative persistence`. At the end of loop `number` variable will be a `multiplicative digital root`.

Output:

```
0 2
```

Also you could do it a bit easier:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long number = 123456789;

    System.out.println(persistenceAndRoot(number));
}

public static List<Long> persistenceAndRoot(long num) {
    long numberOfTimes = 0;
    long temp = num;

    while (num > 9) {
        temp = 1;
        while (num > 0) {
            temp *= num % 10;
            num /= 10;
        }
        num = temp;
        numberOfTimes++;
    }

    return List.of(temp, numberOfTimes);
}
```

Output:

```
[0, 2]
```

Comment: I tried to make it to null but it gives another error. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "[362880, 9]"
 at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:67)
 at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:660)
 at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:778)
 at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:11)

Comment: Also, this error occurs after giving the output , ie. [362880, 9], even though it should have given the output [0, 2]

Comment: It happens, because you are trying to call `parseInt` method on string, which is not a number `"[362880, 9]"`.

Comment: So is there any way to solve the problem?

Comment: But it is not giving the correct output as the first number should be 0 as the multiplication needs to be carried until the number is of 1 digit

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: It did. Thanks.